# Mule uses an outdated version of Drools (5.0.1)

Tags: java, mule, drools

I used update site of Drool 6.1.0 Final and installed the software.
http://download.jboss.org/drools/release/6.1.0.Final/org.drools.updatesite/

When i create a new project in the mule server the drools-core,drools-compiler,drools-api jars are of version 5.0.1.

Will a compatibility problem occur if i use knowledge-api jar of version 6.1.0 ?

Comment: 5.x and 6.x are not compatible - this is a major version number increment.

Comment: You don't mean "relevant" but I don't know what your actual problem is.

Comment: I installed 6.1.0 drools but i found drools jar of 5.0 in mule server. This is my major problem

Comment: So you'll have to use Drools 5.0 when you want to use Mule.

Comment: There's a known issue about freeing Mule from specific Drools dependencies: https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-7944